# when can I separate an infinite series from a sum?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

First of all I apologize if this question turns out to be pretty silly: when can I separate an infinite series from a sum? That is, when $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(x_n + y_n)} =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x_n} +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{y_n}$$ I don't remember this fact very well, I don't know if the space in which the $x_n$ and $y_n$ terms are should be taken into account, or it simply requires convergence.

I appreciate a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

The requirement is simply $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x_n} $ and $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{y_n} $ converges. Here is a counter-example if the above is not satisfied:

> Take $a_n = (-1)^n $ and $ b_n = (-1)^{n+1} $. Then $ a_n + b_n = 0$ for any natural number $ n $, so the left hand side yields $0$. However, the R.H.S. is not convergent at all.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty y_n$ converge, then you can perform this separation. You can show this via taking limits of the partial sums for both of the above series and showing it converges to the left hand side.